# How to reload resources?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my 2d game i have 12 mb graphic resource.I have to reload them when my game resumes.But i have a lot of resources so reloading time is very much(around 5-6 seconds).In this time screen goes to black and i'm sure that some people think that game is broken.Also that's very bad user experience.How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, do a loading screen with progress bar. For good reference you can look at Where's my water after leaving the game and returning.

Comment: Okey but i can't do that.Bacause we can't load textures from different thread.So how can i create loading screen?

Comment: Don't understand the different thread comment. You can load the textures for the loading screen which are supposed to load very fast. Than load all the other textures while showing the loading for 5-6 secs. It can all happen on the same GLThread.

Comment: When i'm loading assets,screen doesn't show animations.It freezes when  it is loading assets.So a different thread is needed for that but it's not possible in that case i think.Is there a way to do that?